# javascript problem in firefox

Tags: javascript

I used a javascript function. It includes form.reset(). It is working finely most browser except in firefox. In firefox, the most of controls are clear but not included hidden fields.
I want to clear hidden field in reset. I don't want to use looping. How to do this?

Comment: Are the hidden fields changed from their default values?

Answer (score 1):

Form.Reset doesn't clear the hidden fields. You can use Jquery as suggested in this post:

[javascript: True form reset for hidden fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559616/javascript-true-form-reset-for-hidden-fields)

Comment: I not want to use looping because the form had many hidden fields.

Comment: Why? Because it will take a long time? I doubt that the user will notice... I could understand your concern if this were happening at the same time as a bunch of other stuff, but unless there are thousands of fields, this will be fast enough. Anyhow the solution is at the bottom of that link: use "display: none".