# Set hidden input value without modifying the attribute

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So many years in web development and still learning.

Is there any way to modify an input element  **of type hidden**'s value without modifying the html attribute? As if the user entered a value. I need to be able to set a value but then upon calling `form.reset()` to return to the original value.

**Notice**: I'm not looking for a workaround, I want to know how to do the thing I asked for in particular.

Comment: what do you mean the original value?  Is this a value that a user set prior, or another value that you set as a default?

Comment: @Berdesdan there is a value attribute that is set *originally*, I want to modify the value but then by calling `form.reset()` to go back to that value.

Comment: reset() should set the original value

Comment: This https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/m4bn7ax3/ works for me, both in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: @ChrisG you are correct, it appears the behavior I'm describing only concerns hidden inputs https://jsfiddle.net/m4bn7ax3/1/

Comment: @php_nub_qq Right, in that case I guess the only solution *is* a workaround. For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559616/javascript-true-form-reset-for-hidden-fields

Comment: Try with `<input hidden>` instead of `<input type="hidden">`

Comment: really dont understand what u want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way to do it properly
https://jsfiddle.net/m4bn7ax3/1/

What if you hide an input text? May it be an acceptable workaround?

```
<input type="text" style="display: none" name="foo" value="original">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `javascript` to set the input field value. Initialise the default value in a variable and then plug that into the input by setting the input field value to that variable in your `form.reset()` method.

```
document.getElementById("idOfInputField").value = defaultValue;
```

Comment: I don't know why this is downvoted. As far as I'm concerned, this is not updating the HTML element.

Comment: @MatiasCicero It does, at least in chrome. FYI  I didn't downvote.